# Too many arguments to constructor of TouchDesigner's

Tags: glsl, shader, alpha

I use TouchDesigner's GLSL. I want to try to make the color transparent like alpha but he will appear too many arguments to constructor of XXX

```c
void main()
{ 
    vec2 r                             = vUV.st;

    vec3 backgroundColor             = vec3(1.0,0,0,0);
    vec3 axesColor                     = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec3 gridColor                     = vec3(0.5);

    // start by setting the background color. If pixel's value
    // is not overwritten later, this color will be displayed.
    vec3 pixel                         = backgroundColor;

    // Draw the grid lines
    // we used "const" because loop variables can only be manipulated
    // by constant expressions.
    const float tickWidth             = 0.1;
    for(float i=0.0; i<1.0; i+=tickWidth) {
        // "i" is the line coordinate.
        if(abs(r.x - i)<0.002) pixel = gridColor;
        if(abs(r.y - i)<0.002) pixel = gridColor;
    }
    // Draw the axes
    if( abs(r.x)<0.005 ) pixel         = axesColor;
    if( abs(r.y)<0.006 ) pixel         = axesColor;


    fragColor                         = TDOutputSwizzle(vec4(pixel, 1.0)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the line

> ```c
> vec3 backgroundColor             = vec3(1.0,0,0,0);
> ```

You have passed 4 arguments to the constructor of `vec3`. A [Vector constructor](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Vector_constructors) take the number of values that the vector stores.
Pass 3 singel floating point values to solve the issue:

```c
vec3 backgroundColor = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

---

The alpha channel is the 4th component. If you want to add an alpha channel, then you have to use `vec4` instead of `vec3`:

```c
void main()
{ 
    vec2 r               = vUV.st;

    vec4 backgroundColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0
    vec4 axesColor       = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); // red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 1
    vec4 gridColor       = vec3(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // red: 0.5, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1

    // start by setting the background color. If pixel's value
    // is not overwritten later, this color will be displayed.
    vec4 pixel           = backgroundColor;

    // Draw the grid lines
    // we used "const" because loop variables can only be manipulated
    // by constant expressions.
    const float tickWidth = 0.1;
    for(float i=0.0; i<1.0; i+=tickWidth) {
        // "i" is the line coordinate.
        if (abs(r.x - i) < 0.002 || abs(r.y - i) < 0.002)
            pixel = gridColor;
    }
    // Draw the axes
    if (abs(r.x) < 0.005 || abs(r.y) < 0.006)
        pixel = axesColor;

    fragColor = TDOutputSwizzle(pixel); 
}
```

Comment: thanks ur feedback, but if i want to let's background Color include alpha channel , how can i to Written that program in my glsl .
sorry for my english.